# How to specify the type of the call for GetDelegateForFunctionPointer System: Func?

Tags: c++, types, clr, marshalling, function-pointers

Task pass callback typeof System::Func to an unmanaged function.

```
   //c++ clr

        class Unmanagement
        {
          void Test()
          {
            Marshal::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(callback,);//<----how to specify the type?
          }
          IntPtr callback;
        }

        bool Init(Func<IntPtr, Int32, Int32,Int32>^ callback)
        {
          Unmanagement a=new Unmanagement;
          IntPtr cb=Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback);
          a->callback=cb;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func<IntPtr, Int32, Int32, Int32>::typeid`?

Comment: In c++ no  such call (::typeid) (;

Comment: Mixer, sorry, but what? You should get type to it http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx and msdn says, that typeid static field is OK to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.aspx (look at examples for C++).

Comment: I apologize.
Visual studio does not show me it in the list of members.
wrote hands and everything is OK